# Assigning values to C# string array based on parameter

Tags: c#, arrays

In C#, I have a string array of values. However, based on a parameter, the array should not include two of the values, but include all the same other values. What's the proper way to approach this? (I could use a list...but I'm hoping there's a better way)

Example code:

```
bool msettingvalue=false;
string[] settings;
if(msettingvalue)
    settings = new string[]{
        "setting1","1",
        "setting2","apple",
        "msetting","true"};
else
    settings = new string[]{
        "setting1","1",
        "setting2","apple"};
//code that goes through settings
```

What's the proper way to assign the array to settings. All the values will be same, it's that if the msettingvalue is false, it should include certain settings.
(You may change the title if you think of a better one).

**Edit1**
Ideally, I'd like to stay with a string[] array vs a dictionary as its faster...and I'm iterating through the array in order so I don't need a key index.

**Edit2**
I've asked a [followup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788431/c-sharp-inline-conditional-in-string-array) question in hopes of there being a way to use an inline conditional for this.

Comment: Look at my answer, I have just edited it, maybe it will be ok for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to use dictionary, you can do take this function:

```
    private static string[] AddSettings(ref string[] settings, params string[] SettingsToAdd)
    {                   
        int length = SettingsToAdd.Length;

        if (length%2 !=0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number of elements");
        }

        int OldLength = settings.Length;
        int NewLength = settings.Length + length;
        Array.Resize(ref settings, NewLength);
        for (int i = OldLength; i < NewLength; i++)
        {
            settings[i] = SettingsToAdd[i - OldLength];
        }
        return settings;
    }
```

**EDIT: Or this version, based on an answer of your other post:**

```
    private static string[] AddSettings(ref string[] settings, params string[] SettingsToAdd)
    {                   
        int length = SettingsToAdd.Length;

        if (length%2 !=0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number of elements");
        }
        else
            return settings.Concat(SettingsToAdd).ToArray();
    }
```

and its use:

```
        bool msettingvalue = true;
        string[] settings;
        settings = new string[]{
            "setting1","1",
            "setting2","apple"};
        if (msettingvalue)
        {
            settings= AddSettings(ref settings,"setting1", "value1", "setting2", "value2", "setting3", "value3");
        }
```

You can then add as many values as you wish, and the count must be a multiple of 2, if not, it throws an exception

Comment: Array.Resize copies the entire array to a new array with that size (and hence is slow)...it'd be faster to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 10):

I have a strong opinion that you should be using `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.

Then you could have:

```
bool msettingValue = false;
Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"setting1", "1"},
    {"setting2", "apple"},
}
if(msettingValue) {
    settings.Add("msetting", "true");
}
```

Comment: I know I can use a dictionary/list...but I'd like to see if there's anything for a string[] array...it's faster.

Comment: @user389823: You say it's faster, but all the mechanisms you'll end up adding to mimic a dictionary (cause that's exactly what it is) is going to be as CPU Time expensive.

Comment: @user389823, that is called "premature optimization" (, a bad habit that is hard to get rid of). What is cheaper: more CPU; or more developer time?

Answer (score 1):

You could go with something like this :

```
Dictionary<string,string> settings = new Dictionary<string,string>();
if (msettingValue) {
   settings["msetting"] = "true";
}
settings["setting1"] = "1";
settings["setting2"] = "apple";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not build the array with the common elements, then add the extra stuff if the bool settings variable is true?