# C# inline conditional in string[] array

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, arrays

How could you do the following inline conditional for a string[] array in C#. Based on a parameter, I'd like to include a set of strings...or not. This question is a followup of [this one on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788270/assigning-values-to-c-sharp-string-array-based-on-parameter).

```
        //Does not compile
        bool msettingvalue=false;
        string[] settings;
        if(msettingvalue)
            settings = new string[]{
                "setting1","1",
                "setting2","apple",
                ((msettingvalue==true) ? "msetting","true" :)};
```

If msettingvalue is true, I'd like to include two strings "msetting","true" : otherwise no strings.

**Edit1**
It doesn't have to be a key value pair...what if it were 5 strings to be (or not to be) added...I didn't think it'd be that tricky.

(Also...could someone with enough rep make a "inline-conditional" or "conditional-inline" tag?)

Comment: Based on your code sample, msettingvalue will always be true inside that array initialisation statement.

Comment: FWIW, perhaps a `Dictionary` or `KeyValuePair[]` (or ...) is better suited for setting pairs?

Comment: Use a dictionary, you're coding yourself into a corner here where there is no reason to do this at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
settings = new string[]{"setting1","1", "setting2","apple"}
    .Concat(msettingvalue ? new string[] {"msetting","true"} : new string[0]);
    .ToArray()
```

Comment: @pst it is only as ugly as given requirement. If I were to define it I would definitely NOT use a string array to store key/value pairs. Probably would be a `Dictionary<key,value>`, in which case you can get away with setting value for given key to null.

Answer (score 5):

use a generic `List<String>`

```
bool msettingvalue=false;
string[] settings;
var s = new List<String>();
s.AddRange({"setting1","1","setting2","apple"});
if(msettingvalue)
    s.AddRange({"msetting","true"});
settings = s.ToArray();
```

But... from the look of your array you'd be better off using a different structure to store these things. It's an associative array you want.  You could use a `Tuple` or a `Dictionary` to model the settings in a way that is easier to handle, and that more accurately reflects the semantics.

```
bool msettingvalue=false;
var settings = new Dictionary<String,String>();
settings.Add("setting1","1");
settings.Add("setting2","value2");
if(msettingvalue)
    settings.Add({"msetting","true");
```

...the last two lines could even be.

```
settings.Add({"msetting",msettingvalue.ToString());
```

Comment: I didn't see that mentioned in the question. Still don't.

Comment: I don't think this answer respects the word "inline" used in the title of the question...